# RHEL "No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it"

Tags: java, ssh, x11

**Situation**

I am connected to a Linux VM via Bastion (provisioned through Azure). I am attempting to execute a configuration file for an application I am setting up but get the following error in my output log:

```
No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.
```

**Attempted fixes**

As per existing Stackoverflow posts, I have tried resolving this by setting `DISPLAY` to various values. Perhaps someone can provide clarification on what this should be set to if I am connecting via Bastion? After I have set this environment variable, I receive this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using '<VariousValuesIveTried>' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.
```

I am quite stuck on this and dont know how to proceed. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: The program you’re running on the Linux host requires a GUI. Is there another way to achieve your overall goal without using a GUI? Otherwise, you’ll need to run an X11 server on your local machine, and set up an SSH tunnel. This is explained in the SSH documentation. Running X over the Internet can be very sluggish. This should be a last resort option.

Comment: Thanks, Tim. Ironically, I am already trying to perform a silent configuration for automation purposes. The task is to perform WebLogic silent configuration (for which there is documentation), but nothing mentioned the issue I am facing unfortunately. Will keep looking...

Comment: You might want to create a new question about the overall problem. Unfortunately, I don't know any specifics about WebLogic myself, but I'm sure others here might. It's probably more on topic for the [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com) site rather than Stack Overflow.